# Cannot retrieve file in assets folder in Android

Tags: java, android, opencv

I can't seem to get this line of code to find this file.

```
Mat topLeftMat = Highgui.imread("newTopLeftMarker.jpg");
```

I've been using this block of code to test to see if it's finding the file. I've tried a bunch of things but none of them have been working.

```
File imgFile = new File("newTopLeftMarker.jpg");
if(imgFile.exists())
{ 
Log.i(TAG, "YES");
} else {
Log.i(TAG, "NO");
}
```

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

To retrieve a document from an asset you have to do something like :

```
final InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open("newTopLeftMarker.jpg");
```